# Launching a video via VLC directly from MacOS command line without any playlist interaction

Tags: macos, command-line, vlc

I posted this originally in Super User, and it was suggested that I post this question here, instead ...

I'm using `VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari` under `MacOS 11.6`.

I want to run VLC from the command line in order to play `videoname.mp4`.

I know I can do the following:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC videoname.mp4
```

However, when I do so, VLC does not start playing the video. Rather, it just displays the VLC playlist GUI window with a `videoname.mp4` line, and I have to click on `videoname.mp4` in this playlist GUI in order to start playing the video.

If I add `--no-playlist-autostart` and `--play-and-exit` command-line options, I get the same behavior.

If I run under Linux, I can use VLC to view the `videoname.mp4` video by running the following command. No playlist GUI window pops up, and the video immediately starts playing:

```
/usr/bin/vlc videoname.mp4
```

Is there a way with the MacOS VLC program to immediately launch a video directly via the command line, without the VLC playlist GUI popping up at all? I want to launch videos from the command line under MacOS in the same manner that I can do it under Linux.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the very helpful feedback from Tetsujin and Jean_JD, I have solved my problem:

(1) Using `Preferences->Show All->Playist->Auto Start` will force the video on the command line to be launched immediately.

(2) Using `Preferences->Video->Show video within main window` will force the video display window to overwrite (and thereby eliminate) the playlist window.

Comment: Happy for you. ;-}

Answer (score 3):

The following example works for me in **Terminal** with default setting in **VLC** and starts the video immediately:

```
open -a VLC '/path/to/filename.mp4'
```

---

In reference to the comment by HippoMan:

> I also often want to pass `--sub-file /path/to/subtitles.srt` , but the following does not work:  `open -a VLC /path/to/file.mp4 --args --sub-file /path/to/subtitles.srt`

If the `.srt` *file* is in the same *directory* as the .`mp4` *file* and is named the same as it, it should get loaded automatically. It does for me, however, the following *example* also works for me as well:

```
screen /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --sub-file '/path/to/filename.srt' '/path/to/filename.mp4' &
```

Note the the *command prompt* does not automatically return after the *command* is executed, however, pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> causes it to return and the *window* can continue to be used or closed without terminating the `vlc` *process*.

Comment: Thank you. That works if I don't want to pass any extra command-line arguments. However, I also often want to pass `--sub-file /path/to/subtitles.srt` , but the following does not work:  `open -a VLC /path/to/file.mp4 --args --sub-file /path/to/subtitles.srt`

Comment: @HippoMan, I've updated my answer to show how to execute `vlc` from the _command line_ with _options.